# Python import package in module behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a behavioral question about Python. Coming from the C background, I understand that modules are not the same as header files.

Here are two scripts:

Module1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import urllib
```

Driver.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import module1
```

The behavior I expected at first was for urllib to be imported along with module1 inside the driver. However, this is not the behavior that I am experiencing. Is it correct to put

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import urllib
import module1
```

Or does that cause urllib to be imported twice?

I read in the documentation that the I can do something like

```
from module1 import urllib
```

but that seems to be too much writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The behavior I expected at first was for `urllib` to be imported along with `module1` inside the driver.

Why should it? You've imported `urllib` inside the namespace (module dictionary) of `module1` and not in that of `Driver`.

`urllib` is imported but, in `module1`, try:

```
import Driver
Driver.module1.urllib
```

and see that no `NameError`s are raised, `urllib` is there.

> does that cause `urllib` to be imported twice?

No, Python will see `urllib` has already been imported (by peeking inside `sys.modules`) and just create an entry for `urllib` in the namespace or `Driver`.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. In C, if I imported some library into a header file and imported the header file into a driver, the entire header file would be imported, including imported libraries. Thank you for clarifying the difference.

Comment: Don't try and draw parallels between `C` and `Python` @Shadowfax . :-) Even though the most popular implementation of Python is implemented in `C` it is a completely different language with different semantics! Take a peek at the [reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html), it clears up pretty much most questions you might encounter.